# Initialize a value for a shared property

Tags: vb.net

I want to use a counter for how many objects are created from a single class, so I thought that a Shared Property would be the way to go.  But, VB doesn't like that and says, "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class"

```
Private _Length As Integer = 0
Public Shared Property Length As Integer
    Get
        Return _Length
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _Length = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Is there a way to initialize a shared variable, in this case to zero, and have the Property still function correctly.  I used the Java get/set methodology (getLength()/setLength())and that worked fine, but I'm sure that it would be frowned up by VBers.

Also, using two variables to get/set one that is actually used seems a bit redundant.  I see why it is used in the VB methodology because of the recursion that happens, but it does look strange.

Comment: aaarrrrgggg....  I forgot the Shared infront of _Length.

Comment: it also isnt "using two variables" and there is no recursion.

Comment: Before I realized how Property worked, I just tried to use Length = value in the Set and VB said to make sure that I didn't have an infinite loop or recursion, which seemed to be happening because the Set would keep calling itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backing field `_Length` must also be shared.

```
Private Shared _Length As Integer = 0
```

> using two variables to get/set one that is actually used seems a bit
>   redundant.

You don't have two variables just one which is `_Length`, a property just manages how you can access that variable. Note that even [auto implemented properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) like this use a backing-field:

```
Public Property Length As Int32
```

You just don't see it since it will be generated for you.

Comment: Yep.  That was the problem.  I feel stupid, but at least it was a simple fix.

Comment: If Mr Schmelter's answer helped clarify things, click the checkmark so this falls off the unanswered list.